# How to index rebuild in MySQL for all tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

5 and i have to do index rebuild for all tables in a database which is in InnoDB. i know Optimize which did at table level. Is there any way to do this for all tables in a database in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```

Comment: How to validate that table indexes were updated with Index Rebuild?

Comment: what is the syntax for a particular db only not on all DB?

Comment: @VikrantMore:- If you want to validate the index then you need to use the Analyze command for a specific table like `ANALYZE TABLE tablename;`

Comment: @VikrantMore:- For a particular database you need to provide the database name instead of `--all-databases`

Comment: can you give me the syntax here.

Comment: With mysql 5.7 this suggested command yielded the following error `Error:  mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple contradicting commands.`

Answer (score 0):

Just use sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysqlcheck -u root -p --optimize --all-databases, when asked for password just press enter

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)